# Why does my python's socket.shutdown work on Windows but not Ubuntu?

Tags: python, sockets, windows-7, udp, ubuntu-13.10

Here is what my socket code looks like, this is for a UDP connection.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.settimeout(8)
sock.sendto(req, (host, port))
buf = sock.recv(2048)
sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
sock.close()
```

Here is the relevant portion of my stack trace

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "udp_test.py", line 110, in my_method
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I don't know what OS the host is running, I assume it is some flavor of Linux. I can wrap the `socket.shutdown`<sup>[[docs]](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown)</sup> call in a try catch and everything seems to work fine.

Does this problem have something to do with a difference between the way Windows and Linux handle sockets? Is wrapping `sock.shutdown` in a try catch the solution here or will I run nasty problems down the rode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `sock.shutdown()` on a *UDP* socket. UDP doesn't have a connection to shut down. On Windows the call doesn't do much other than prevent you from writing to and reading from the socket (packets are still received and queued), on Linux calling shutdown on a UDP connection throws an error.

In either case, you shouldn't really be using `shutdown` at all. Just close the socket instead, or just don't send on the socket and don't read data from it.